# dataTable is not updating even refreshing the page

Tags: jsf

in my xhtml page i have

```
<h:dataTable value="#{testController.items}" var="item" border="0">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
    </h:column>           
</h:dataTable>
```

it correctly displays the list of item names in the database. My problem is, whenever i try to create or delete an item, even tho i hit f5 or refresh the page manually, the items in the data table does not change. it somehow only updates the table when i clear my browser's cache.

```
public DataModel getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();
    }
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint in the corresponding getter of testController (getItems()...) and check whether this getter gets actually called on a refresh. could you maybe post the code of the controller?

Comment: hi, ive updated the question. im actually using the CRUD auto generate controller

Comment: Please refer to [JSF Using datatables](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html) by BalusC (JSF expert). Note that the doc is for JSF 1.2, but it also works for JSF 2 by just adding the annotations in your managed bean. I would use `@ViewScoped` annotation instead of `@SessionScoped`.

Comment: using @viewScoped worked too. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What scope do you have? 
Well as it seems from your code, your items won't get loaded again on a refresh, because they are already initialized at this moment. Tray to remove the if-statement and check if the items get reloaded after a refresh then.

Comment: weird. i followed your advice and removed the if-statement, so only the return item is left, it wont display any item. so i tried putting back `items = getPagination().createPageDataModel();` without the if then it worked. but i dont understand why..

Comment: that's what I meant. If you dont check whether items is null or not and reload them every time the getter is called, then it should work fine.